# How to find files in subdirs and sort them by filename in a single command?

Tags: find, filenames, sort

Result of a normal find using `find . ! -path "./build*" -name "*.txt"`:

```
./tool/001-sub.txt
./tool/000-main.txt
./zo/001-int.txt
./zo/id/002-and.txt
./as/002-mod.txt
```

and when sorted with `sort -n`:

```
./as/002-mod.txt
./tool/000-main.txt
./tool/001-sub.txt
./zo/001-int.txt
./zo/id/002-and.txt
```

however the desired output is:

```
./tool/000-main.txt
./zo/001-int.txt
./tool/001-sub.txt
./zo/id/002-and.txt
./as/002-mod.txt
```

which means output is sorted based on *filename only*, but folder information should be maintained as part of the output.

**Edit**: Make example more complicated as the subdirectory structure may include more than one level.

Comment: See this question I asked on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3222810/sorting-on-the-last-field-of-a-line

Comment: @camh - if possible I would like to use only unix commands. In any case my question is pretty much a duplicate of yours. Can you transfer the best solution to this thread (keep a link to the original anyways) so I can mark is as the solution?

Comment: If @Shawn makes the changes I suggested in my comment (use `-printf` instead of `awk`), I think that is the best solution. I've reworked my original implementation to use this method.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to sort by the last field (considering `/` as a field separator). Unfortunately, I can't think of a tool that can do this when the number of fields varies (if only `sort -k` could take negative values).

To get around this, you'll have to do a decorate-sort-undecorate. That is, take the filename and put it at the beginning followed by a field separator, then do a sort, then remove the first column and field separator.

```
find . ! -path "./build*" -name "*.txt" |\
    awk -vFS=/ -vOFS=/ '{ print $NF,$0 }' |\
    sort -n -t / |\
    cut -f2- -d/
```

That `awk` command says the *field separator* `FS` is set to `/`; this affects the way it reads fields. The *output field separator* `OFS` is also set to `/`; this affects the way it prints records. The next statement says print the last column (`NF` is the number of fields in the record, so it also happens to be the index of the last field) as well as the whole record (`$0` is the whole record); it will print them with the OFS between them. Then the list is `sort`ed, treating `/` as the field separator - since we have the filename first in the record, it will sort by that. Then the `cut` prints only fields 2 through the end, again treating `/` as the field separator.

Comment: Since this is with find(1), you can skip the awk part and use `-printf '%f/%p\n'`

Comment: indeed our setup is slightly more complicated. It does include variable subdir depths. Edited the question to reflect this fact. My apologies for not including this at first.

Comment: @Unode: Shawn's solution handles variable depth just fine, it's the canonical solution to this problem (up to minor variations).

Answer (score 6):

I would use files '-printf' to output name and path, sort by name, and cutoff the name in a last step. '###' is just a marker, to help cutting.

```
find -name "*.txt" -printf "%f###%p\n" | sort -n | sed 's/.*###//'
```

%f prints the filename, %p the whole path.

I simplified the find-command to get it into one line, of course you would leave the `! -path "./build*"` part.

Answer (score 3):

In zsh ≥4.3.10:

```
print -l -- **/*.txt~build*(oe\''REPLY=${REPLY:t}'\')
```

- `**/*.txt` matches `*.txt` in the current directory and its subdirectories [recursively](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Recursive-Globbing).
- `~build*` [excludes](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Operators) matches whose text begins with `build*` (like `! -path './build*'`). (You need `setopt extended_glob` first.)
- `(oe\''…'\')` is a sorting [glob qualifier](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers). `REPLY=…` constructs the string to sort from the string to return.
- `${REPLY:t}` is the [basename](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Modifiers) (“tail”) of the path.

Comment: Lots of concatenated magic. Interesting but we are limited to sh syntax. +1